# Node JS detect connectivity to all Node JS programs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, electron, backend

Let me describe it as briefly and clearly as possible:

I have 10 different copies of a node JS based program running on 10 different desktops. I want to create a Node JS based (or any other technology) web app deployed on a server which will check if these 10 programs are online or not.

Any suggestions as to how I can implement this?
Note: The node JS based desktop apps are running on electron.

Comment: Looks like a use case for `socket.io`

Comment: WebSockets or a simple HTTP request or a TCP/UDP message, or, or, or...

Comment: But what exactly @Danizavtz? How can I do it in the background without bothering or slowing down the main process, keeping in mind internet might go on and off..

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 most probable ways.

1. if you want to know immediately whether out of 10 programs, if any of them goes offline then you should use Socket.io

- Your server nodejs program will act as server and your 10 desktop program will work as client. Your 10 client socket connection will connect with server socket connection and server socket can check whether socket client is still connected or not based on Ping/Pong concept of socket.

in brief, Ping/pong technique in which server sends Ping event on socket connection and client will receive server's ping event and send Pong event back to server.
if client is not sending Pong event back in predefined time interval on getting Ping event then that client is offline or disconnected.

2. You can periodically (say every 1/5/10 minutes etc ) call simple HTTP request and check if response status is 200 or not. If any of the 10 desktop program is offline then you will know it by response status whether it is 200 or not.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use socket.io for this there may also be a simpler way and that is to just use a post request / cron to check every X minutes if the server is reachable from 'Checking' server (that would just be the server that is doing the check)

So why not use socket.io? Well, without knowing how you node servers are setup, its hard to say if socket.io would be a good fit, this is simply because socket.io uses WSS to connect, so unless you are running it from the browser it will need additional configurations / modules setup on the server to actually use WSS (if you do go this route, you will need socket.io-client module on each system, this is important because this will allow you to connect to the socket.io server, also make sure the version of socket.io matches the socket.io-client build)

All in all, if I was building this out, I would probably just do a simple ping of each server and log it to a DB or what not but your requirements will really dictate the direction you go